# RegEx match URL to contain /wp-content/

Tags: javascript, regex, wordpress

I need to check an anchor path for containing /wp-content/ .

For instance, `<a href="http://domain.com/wp-content/...">Link1</a>`

In this case the RegExp must match pattern with url and return string in array

`['http://domain.com', 'domain.com', 'http://domain.com/wp-content/', '']`

In my code I use this but I do something wrong

```
$('a').live('click', function(e) {
     var host = thisClick.attr('href'),
         pattern = /(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(.*?)?(\/wp-content\/)?\//,
         matchReg = host.match(pattern);
});
```

What's wrong with up line code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See what happens when you apply your regex:

1. First character, `<`, doesn't match `h` in `(?:https?:\/\/)?`. Moving on.
2. Doesn't match `w` in `(?:www\.)?`, moving on
3. DOES match `.` in `(.*?)?`
4. The quantifier will go on as long as it doesn't match a `/` or a `/wp-content/`
5. You end up with `<a href="http:/` matched.

You can't make everything optional, or there isn't any anchor the regex can work on to get to the start of the URL. If you're trying to always  match something in a `<a>` tag, try:

```
/href="(((?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(.*?)?)\/wp-content\//
```

- Non optional `/wp-content/`, that's your criteria.
- No additional forward slash after the one from `wp-content/`
- First group will capture `http://domain.com/wp-content/`, second `http://domain.com`, third `domain.com`
- Demo for fun here: http://regex101.com/r/lF5qO7

Comment: Thanks, Robin for extended answer
Now everything is understandable and your code above works fine as I wanted.